# Tableau Logarithm worksheet displays inconsistently

Tags: tableau-api

I have a worksheet where I can show a logarithmic graph for 'ALL' partitions and get exactly what I want.  However, if I select to display only a particular partition, the displayed results are Not the same. The only difference is that I have a filter to select individual partitions.

This is a problem both in Desktop, and also on the Tableau Server.  Tableau Version 2019.2

Notice partition 8702.  The Blue line should hover just above or on the yellow area.

Thank you.

FIG 1.
The ALL display.
[image]

FIG 2.
The 8702 partition selected only.
[image]

I turned on Show Mark Labels.  Now I can see that on an item (1400) there is a order-qty (blue line is 13) while the yellow sales mark is 12.   Those are converted-to log numbers, but I see the 13 (order-qty) IS greater than the sales number (12)...... It's just not converting the two graphs on the same scale.  I think that's my problem.   Maybe I am misusing the logrithmic chart.  Am hoping I am making sense..

[image]

Comment: can you post the formulas for both calculations? Is the level of detail the same for both?

Comment: Hi.  Yes, the formulas are the same.  Only difference in the second example FIG 2, is that I use a filter to select whse 8702 only.  It should display the same results though the graph will be bigger because less data is being displayed.  There are two graphs here sharing the axis.   The blue line-chart, layed over the yellow area graph.

Comment: The Yellow is a simple sum(sales).... the blue line is a simple sum(ordered-qty)

Comment: If an order-qty is 2 and a sales is 1.  I would expect the blue line to rest just above the yellow sales area graph.  I would not expect the blue line (order-qty) to display down in the middle of sales--even in a logarithmic graph.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help but on the dual chart have you right-clicked on the header and selected Synchronize Axis?

Comment: @vizyourdata... you are RIGHT.   that was exactly it.   I thought  I came back and answered my question with a screen shot of setting that property.... Thank you though...

Comment: you're welcome. happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESOLVED:  Once I realized there was a problem with the scales being different.  I found that if I right-click on the Edit Axis, I can set the axis to Syncronized.  I did this for both Axis's of the chart.
[image]